# how to get Android-Studio modules name I Intellij Plugin development

Tags: java, android-studio, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I want to develop plugin for Android studio for this I am using Intellij idea plugin APIs. For this I need to get project module names in project. Can anyone suggest how i can get list of modules in android studio project using intellij plugin APIs.

Comment: Is this a code related question?

Answer (score 1):

`com.intellij.openapi.module.ModuleManager#getModules`